# What's the usage of tesseract useROI method?

Tags: c#, methods, ocr, tesseract

Is there a documentation for tesseract dotnetwrapper? as in like a java doc or something? I'm trying to understand what this useROI method does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check its [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/wiki/tesseract_engine_v3_01r590_dotnet_wrapper) page. UseROI specifies a region of interest on the image to be recognized.